# How to detect on which site am I?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am using WordPress "multisite" for different languages on my site, and I want to know how can I know on which site am I. I can easily check which page is it, but for the site, It is little bit tricky. I have made site for Eng, and site for Fr, and couple more.

So far I have tried to check URL with :

```
stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/Eng/')
```

Is there different way to do this?

Comment: Does the code you have now not work, or why do you need a different way?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_blog_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_current_blog_id()`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_blog_id

E.g.

```
$blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
```

I'd do something like:

```
if ( 1 === $blog_id ) {
    echo 'This is the Eng site.';
}
```

If there are multiple language options to test you'd be better with a switch:

```
switch ( $blog_id ) {
    case 1:
        echo 'This is the Eng site.';
        break;
}
```

Comment: You could even put the result of Nathan's site test into a $_SESSION variable and use that across your site?